# Why only date and price is changing and not the title in this React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react from udemy and I came across this lecture of adding stateful list but it is not updating and I can only see change in date and price but not the title.
The code is similar because I am doing the stuff he is doing in the course as well .
Error is it is not updating expenses instead adding last expense repeatedly.

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYUqi.png)

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Expenses from "./components/Expenses/Expenses";
import NewExpense from "./components/NewExpenses/NewExpense";

const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
  {
    id: 'e1',
    title: 'Toilet Paper',
    amount: 94.12,
    date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
  },
  { 
    id: 'e2', 
    title: 'New TV', 
    amount: 799.49, 
    date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
  {
    id: 'e3',
    title: 'Car Insurance',
    amount: 294.67,
    date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
  },
  {
    id: 'e4',
    title: 'New Desk (Wooden)',
    amount: 450,
    date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
  },
];

function App() {
  

  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);


  const addExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
    setExpenses((prevExpenses) => {
      return[expense, ...prevExpenses];
    });
    console.log(DUMMY_EXPENSES);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Let's Get Started</h1>
      <NewExpense onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler} />
      <Expenses items={expenses}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NewExpenses.js**

```
import React from "react";
import './NewExpense.css';
import ExpenseForm from './ExpenseForm';

const NewExpense = (props) => {

    const savedExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData) => {
        const expenseData = {
            ...enteredExpenseData,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        };
        console.log(expenseData);

        props.onAddExpense(expenseData); // This is the function from App.js . sending data to App.js
    };

    return (
        <div className="new-expense">
            <ExpenseForm onSavedExpenseData={savedExpenseDataHandler} />
        </div>

    );
}

export default NewExpense;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the way you're updating the state of expenses in the addExpenseHandler function. You're using the DUMMY_EXPENSES array to console log the expenses, but that array is not being updated when a new expense is added. Instead, you should be console logging the expenses array which is being updated with the new expense.

Also, it looks like you're not updating the title of the expense in the addExpenseHandler function. You should be copying over the title from the expense object and updating it in the new object that you're creating.

Here's the updated addExpenseHandler function:

```
const addExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
 setExpenses((prevExpenses) => {
  return [{...expense}, ...prevExpenses];
 });
console.log(expenses);
};
```

Note that we're spreading the expense object and copying over all its properties including the title. And we're console logging the expenses array which is being updated with the new expense.

Also, make sure to update the ExpenseForm.js component to include the title field in the expense object that is passed to the savedExpenseDataHandler function.

Comment: Still not working
I am changing title just like date and price but don't know why it is not changing.
The major problem is array is not getting updated. I can only see 4 array elements in console.log(). and don't know why the last element ( New Wooden ) is getting duplicated when I add new expense .